# How to redefine the chapter like the following?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, bookmarks

I have a newcommand to redefine chapter.

```
\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{
\clearpage
% \noindent
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\begin{center}
    \dsp{CHAPTER\space\thechapter\\}
    \vspace{10pt}
    \ssp\uppercase{#1}
    \vspace{-5pt}
\end{center}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{3pt}}     
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{
    \protect
    \makebox[0.75in][r]{\thechapter.}
    \hspace*{3pt} 
    \uppercase{#1}
}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{10pt}} }
```

But here comes the problem, on each bookmark of pdf, there is `[0.75in][r]` as the prefix, which is the option of `\makebox`. For example: `[0.75in][r]1.Introduction`

How to redefine it and remove that prefix?

The `\makebox` will indent the chapter line 0.75in right

[image: indent chapter]

but have the prefix in the bookmark

[image: bookmark]

If remove `[0.75in][r]`, there will be no indent space, but the bookmark title is clean.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! What are you trying to achieve by redefining chapter? Knowing this could help answerers to provide you with alternatives.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `\makebox{}` etc. in the `\addcontentsline{}` code?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Actually, I am using the template class, the purpose of using `\makebox` is to indent proper in the toc, I guess.

Comment: @Kimmi: Well, rather no... Normally, you don't have to use the `\makebox` for the TOC entries. You should show us the template and tell us, as T.Verron already asked of you, what you really want to achieve

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I updated the question again. How to remove the prefix in the bookmark title, and also leave the chapter line indent properly?

Comment: @Kimmi: There are commands missing `\dsp` and `\ssp`... The whole stuff is not well-designed in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That is double spaced / single spaced. Here is the original definition. http://www.iit.edu/graduate_college/academic_affairs/pdfs/iitthesis

Comment: @Kimmi: Even with that thesis class on my computer, I can't compile your code

Comment: There are packages designed to alter or customize the chapter titles. One of the most prominent ones for the standard classes is `titlesec`. Redefining `\chapter` from scratch will be error-prone.